# What methods are there for representing 3D terrain?

Tags: procedural-generation, terrain

I'm making a terrain system which needs to be procedurally generated and would like to know my options. So far I know of: Height-field terrain, Vector-field terrain, and Voxel terrain. Is there anything missing from that list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a quick note about voxel landscapes. It is a wide field and there are a variety of representations and algorithms for display.

**Heightfield voxel terrain**: stored as a heightmap, but rendered with vertical strips rather than polygons. Check out "[Outcast](http://mpierce.pie2k.com/pages/109.php)"

**Cuboid terrain**: I believe stored in terrain chunks as run-length encoded strips. Displayed as a bunch of quads, separating empty voxels from solid ones. We all know [minecraft](https://minecraft.net/).

**Polygonised scalar field**: A voxel field of real values representing signed distance from surface. Surface is extracted with a polygonisation algorithm like "marching cubes", "marching tetrahedrons" or "dual contouring". See this [GPU Gems article](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch01.html).

**Sparse voxel octrees**: Stored as a memory efficient octree, and rendered by raycasting the tree directly. This technique has great potential but is still in its infancy. Check out [Atomontage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sfWYUgxGBE)

Comment: Polygonised scalar field. So that's the name for that subset.